# How to create a specific class for a collection in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I want to create a specific class to manage a collegion in my application.

For example, I have a Store and I have a list of customers in a collection, in this collection I have a customer that is the customer of the month, and some customers that got a prize to get a discount for some reason. Let's get to the code:

```
public class Store {
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public Customer CustomerOfTheMonth 
    {
        //get and set for customer of the month
    }
    public ICollection<Customer> DiscountCustomers 
    {
        //get and set for customer of the month
    }
    public ICollection<Customer> GetAllCustomers 
    {
        //get and set for customer of the month
    }
}
```

But in my database, I only have two tables. Store, and Customer.

What I want to do is create a specific collection for the customer, to remove the logic from the Store and put in a specific class, after all, I don't feel that the logic belongs to neither of those classes.

I wans tomething like this:

```
public class Store {
    internal CustomerCollection Customers { get; set; }

    //get and set for the propertis, just delegating for the collection
}        

public class CustomerCollection {
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Customer> DiscountCustomers 
    {
        //get and set for customer of the month
    }

    //get and set with logic to filter the collection
}
```

Is there  away to create this mapping and keep with only two tables in the database? I want to make it transparent to the application. Sorry for the code problems, typed in stack overflow and didn't check the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't need to create your business logic to your model classes. Separate your logic to upper level. Here are your model classes. It will create your relationships as you want

```
public class Store {
        public vertual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        //get and set for other propertis
    } 



public class Customer{

    //get and set for other propertis
}
```

Create a repository or service layer to apply specific business logic ,

```
 public ICollection<Customer> GetDiscountCustomers() 
    {
       return dbContext.Customers.where(c=>c.discount=true).ToList()
    }
```

if you want to load stores with customers at once you can use eager loading,

```
public ICollection<Store> GetAllStores() 
        {
           return dbContext.Stores.Include("Customers").ToList()
        }
```

Comment: When I load the Store, the Customers are loaded together, and I don't want to separate it.

Comment: Then you can use eager loading.